# Dynamically create buttons in a ListView [android]

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I am trying to make a simple application, where only one button is initially displayed. 
What I want to do is whenever the user clicks on it, another (clickable) button appears underneath.
I've been trying with this code but it doesn't seem to work (there's a NullPointerException)... and internet couldn't help.
Here's my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffc1c1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:text="add button"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

.. and here's my java code:

```
public class ListButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private Button add;
    private Button b1, b2, b3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        final Button[] statesList = {b1,b2,b3};
        b1 = add;
        b2 = add;
        b3 = add;
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

                ArrayAdapter<Button> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Button>(chatActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, statesList);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

U're making too mucho for too little.
just remove the listview from your layout. and instead add another button, but change it's visibility to false.
And, when the user clicks the button, change its visibility to true

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.charlie.testandroidstudioinmac.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Button1"
    android:onClick="btn1Clicked"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My second Button"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And your activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void btn1Clicked(View view){
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

But if you must use a ListView, you need tu use a CustomAdapter instead of

```
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 //this is predefined for textonly listviews
```

Comment: That's not exactly what i was trying to do... I want the user to add as much buttons as he wants. I cannot forsee the number of buttons he will ask and i don't want to create a thousand buttons in the javacode either. Do you think there's a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new item to `stateslist`. After that you need to show the adapter that you have added a new item.

For that just use the method `notifyDataSetChanged()` in adapter and you will have a new item added.

Comment: Could you please develop? I added a button to statesList with an append method, and wrote "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" after the definition pf the adapter, but the emulator gives me a nullPointerException. It says i'm trying to invoke a toString on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
Still no need for a listview, ListView is a little complex for new users.
just add this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create New Button"
    android:onClick="createBtnClicked"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ll_btns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And on your MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LinearLayout ll;
int cont=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_buttons);

    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_btns);

}

public void createBtnClicked(View v){
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("tbn "+cont++);
    ll.addView(btn);
}
```

There.. you can add as many buttons as android memory can support.